# Flutter and keys: can the framework assign a key automatically

Tags: flutter

Is there any reason that the Flutter initState function in a stateful widget can't assign a unique key to the state object and pass that to the widget.  This is easier than passing a key to the widget constructor because you don't always have a suitable key.

If this works then why doesn't the framework do this itself when createState is called to create the stateful widget?  I bet Flutter keys trip a lot of people up because they tripped me up.